# How to package sites so it is available to other Orgs who installs my app?

Tags: force.com-sites, package, package-install

In my salesforce app, there is an options to send emails to the user. The email contains a link on which when the user clicks, goes to a url and shows a visualforce page. The url is a `Site Url`, which I got after creating a `Site`. Now, I want to publish the app. But, there is no any option to add `Site` to the package. So, how can I solve this issue? Is there any other way to make the site available to other Orgs who installs my app?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sites cannot be packaged. You can package all other resources on which your site depends like visualforce pages or lightning components.

To deploy sites to the org there will be some manual steps required in the org and it is adviced to provide a post install instruction documents to the customers on how to set these sites up.

Comment: In my case, there are bunch of things to be done on the Site `Public Access Settings` for the app to work properly. So, I have to provide instructions so that the customer can to do all this stuff?

Comment: @Jayesh that is correct!!!

Comment: K. Thanks very much